# Cmake using chinese single quotation marks

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake

I'm using wsl with clion coding cpp program.

When a error occurred, cmake using chinese single quotation marks result in gibberish in messages of clion like below:

```
error: expected 鈥�;鈥� at end of member declaration
```

However, bash shows:

```
error: expected ‘;’ at end of member
```

`‘` `’` is chinese single quotation marks.

Wsl is using C.UTF-8.

What causes those gibberish? How could I fix it?

Comment: How are you using WSL without bash?

Comment: Clion can access wsl by ssh. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html

Comment: (1) In *Settings > File Encodings*, is IDE Encodings defined as UTF-8? (2) If you have somewhere the file `rubymine.sh`, add `export XMODIFIERS=""` right after the shebang.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.However, I already set all file encodings as utf-8, it does't make any difference.Also I searched my computer and couldn't find a file named "rubymine.rs".

Comment: Maybe it's a bug of clion : ), I'll submit a report to Jetbrain.

Comment: `rubymine.sh` not `rubymine.rs`.